# what will happen to built in apps in galaxy note 1 n7000 after hard reset such as s pen?

Tags: recovery-mode, factory-reset, default-applications

my gt n7000 is getting slow, sometimes it restarts by itself and some application close by itself. i presumed the low device memory was behind all f this.i want to ask if hard reset will solve my memory problem and what will happen to my built in apps such as S-pen? will they still working or i have to reinstall it again? please i need your suggestion. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The types of problems you're describing are generally best solved by, indeed, factory resetting. If you can't find another solution, it's pretty much always the last resort. So if you're willing to do it, it's all but guaranteed to fix the problem, unless the problem is being caused by a hardware issue.

Built-in apps will all remain. Anything that shipped with the phone will still be there. Some may have updates that need to be reapplied, but you won't lose anything that was there when you first turned on your phone after buying it.

Comment: so i just go to setting- backup and reset- factory data reset? so the only missing apps are the additional one which i downloaded from google playstore? how do i backup my apps to my sd card?

Comment: sorry i was too exited to hear your answer, thanks so much for your reply.

Comment: That's correct. And unless you're rooted, you can't backup your apps to your SD card. But you may wish to try the app Helium which has some limited app backup abilities without root.